# Using a query scope in a collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel, scope, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My Association model looks like this (irrelevant code redacted):

```
class Association extends Model
{
    public function members() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Member');
    }

}
```

My Member model looks like this:

```
class Member extends Model
{
    public function scopeActive($query) {
        return $query->where('membership_ended_at', Null);
    }
    public function scopeInactive($query) {
        return $query->whereNotNull('membership_ended_at');
    }
}
```

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
$association = Association::find(49);
$association->members->active()->count();
```

Now, I'm aware there's a difference between a Query and a Collection. But what I'm basically asking is if there's some kind of similar scope for collections. Of course, the optimal solution would be to not have to write TWO active methods, but use one for both purposes.

Comment: Does `$association->members()->active()->count();` work?

Comment: Wow. I guess I got fooled by it allowing me to do `$association->members`

Thanks!

Comment: If you just do `$association->members` you'll get all the associated members, not just the active once... Just so you know

Answer (score 16, accepted):

(question already answered in the comments, but might as well write a proper answer)

It is not possible to use a query scope in a `Colletion`, since query scope is a concept used in Eloquent to add constraints to a database query while `Collections` are just a collection of things (data, objects, etc).

In your case, what you need to do is to change this line:

```
$association->members->active()->count();
```

to:

```
$association->members()->active()->count();
```

This works because when we call `members` as a method, we are getting a `QueryBuilder` instance, and with that we can start chaining scopes to the query before calling the `count` method.